# How can I find the files that were affected by my last pull?

Tags: git, git-pull

I have a `dev` branch. I pulled code from a remote branch, i.e. `origin/dev`.

How would I know how many files are affected in my last `git pull` command?

Comment: Something like `git diff --name-only origin/dev@{1}..origin/dev | wc -l`

Answer (score 2):

Well due to the fact you pulled and this means you also merged automatically this is kind of hard to establish. But, if you know the last commit before you pulled you could do a

`git diff --name-only <lastcommit>..HEAD`

If you want to avoid a automatic merge and see what files will be affected you could do the following:

```
git remote update -p
git diff --name-only master..origin/master
```

This will only fetch the changes into your working tree but will not perform a merge.

Comment: ckruczek@ I don't know the last commit. I just pull the code and other commits added in "git log".

Comment: But you maybe remember the last commit you did right? So you can access git log and look for the last commit you did.

Comment: ckruczek@ yeah. Thanks.

Comment: So if this answer was helpfull Ill frankly remind you to vote/accept it.

Comment: For now I can say thanks only because I'm new in stackoverflow and don't have permission to up your vote. Thanks again.